# How to write business objects with uses Bean Validation in JavaEE?

Tags: java, validation, jsf, ejb, cdi

I'm learning Bean Validation and in the books it is recommended that only business objects should use  bean validation and so that validation should count for  all other layers in a classic mutlitiered JavaEE application. That means bean validation should be implemented only once. But how I should manage that?

Lets say I have following layers in my Java application:

```
JSF-UI->Controller->DTO->EJB/CDI (with Business objects)->DAO->Database
```

How the controller in the frontend should know anything about validation which occurs in the logic layer in the business objects?

Comment: Try reading this article for Bean validation [link]  (http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.com.au/p/validation-in-jsf.html)

Comment: The default behavior is already that JSF fully transparently recognizes and performs bean validation in UI and just show constraint validation errors as faces messages associated with input components. Are you implying that this didn't happen for you at all and that constraint validation errors are only thrown by JPA? Or is this all purely theoretical and didn't you actually tried/tested anything yourself?

Comment: OffTopic: A DTO that accesses 'services'? (Assuming the EJB/CDI layer are services). Or does the controller access the services and do they need DTO's as parameters and return DTO's from method calls?

Comment: Kukeltje yeah you are rigth -> the dto's are just parameters for the service methods

Comment: BalusC: I know that JSF and JPA recognize bean validation -> the problem is: Do I have to annotate my jSF classes and my JPA classes so that bean validation is counting what would be bad because i have to annotate in two layers (-> redundant) or is there a way only to annotate the business object in the service layer  which is then validated by the JSF and JPA-layer?

Comment: or just explaining it with the example above: jsf would only validate the controller class but not the the ejb/cdi-layer underneath